# (Javascript) How can I seperate a string based on an if statement that checks for a number?

Tags: javascript

So i'm trying to build a function that can simplify expressions but I can't seem to find a way to seperate the terms into 2 different arrays (numbers and letters). The result of the code below is "32xy" instead of just "32".

Also it would be great to know if there is a better way to check for a number or selection of characters in javascript.

```
var newArr;
var numArr = [];
var letArr = [];
function splitTerm (term) {
    for (var i=0; i<term.length; i++){
        newArr = term.split(''); 
    }
    for (var item of newArr){
        if (item === '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9') {
            numArr.push(item);
        } else {
            letArr.push(item);
        }
    }
    $('#num').html(numArr.join(''));
}
splitTerm("32xy");
```

Comment: You have to check each string individually, you can not chain conditions like this. Also you could just use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Finally, instead of adding the result to the DOM, you should return it.

Comment: made a jsfiddle here to illustrate my code: https://jsfiddle.net/j23xn08b/

Comment: Thanks TKoL, it works. I also found that using a switch statement worked as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (item === '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9')`

This should be

```
if (['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].includes(item)) {
```

Also, you do'nt need to do that loop at the top of the function.

`newArr = term.split('');`  is fine to just run once.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was an accident. How did I not realise lol.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be improved in many ways:

1. `newArr`, `numArr`, and `letArr` are only used inside the function, so you should declare them inside the function.
2. The for loop iterating from `0` to `term.length` does nothing except repeatedly assign the same thing to `newArr`, so it doesn't need to be there.
3. You can use a regex to test if something is a number.

```js
function splitTerm(term) {
    var newArr = term.split("");
    for (var item of newArr) {
        if (/\d/.test(item)) {
            newArr.push(item);
        } else {
            letArr.push(item);
        }
    }
    $("#num").html(numArr.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option - use regex

```js
const splitTerm = (str) => {
  // Use regexp to extract characters and digits
  return {
    dig: str.match(/\d+/g).join(''),
    char: str.match(/[^\d]+/g).join(''),
  };
};

// Run
const res = splitTerm("32xy");

// Log
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the edited version

```js
var newArr;
var numArr = [];
var letArr = [];
function splitTerm (term) {
    numArr = Array.from(term).filter((elem) => /^[0-9]$/i.test(elem));   
    
    console.log(numArr.join(''));
}
splitTerm("322xy");
```

but you can actually use the value directly without function call;

```js
 $('#num').html(Array.from('32xy').filter((elem) => /^[0-9]$/i.test(elem)).join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .replace() with regular expression in your function.

```js
console.log("32xy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')); // 32
console.log("aaa32xy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')); // 32
console.log("aaa3bb2xy".replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')); // 32
```